# Finding a vector equation for a trajectory

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

> A shell is fired from the ground with muzzle speed of 320 ft/s and
>   elevation angle of 60 degrees (assume $g=32 \, \mbox{ft}/\mbox{s}^2$)
>
> Find a vector equation for the shell's trajectory

I'm not looking for the precise answers but what should i do with this problem? Am i supposed to get the velocity components of x and y? Pls any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: As you are not looking for a precise answer, I will just leave a hint.  Assuming wind resistance is not a factor (which is a big assumption) the horizontal component of velocity will be constant.  I suggest you consider the initial conditions, then consider what does gravity do to the vertical component?

Answer (score 0):

A trajectory is the curve of positions of the shell, a parabola (we assume the earth is flat and do not shoot too fast, neglect air friction etc.).

The usual parameterization of the curve is by time.

So I assume $r(t) = (x(t), y(t))^t$ is wanted.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. So like the vector should be < (320cos60)t , (320sin60)t-16t^2 > right?